# search and replace a string in a pdf using python

Tags: pdf, python-2.7, replace

I have a multipage pdf document and I am trying to find a specific pattern of string in it (may be one or more lines ) and replace it with some other string using python.Is it possible to do this with python ??

Thanks!

Comment: Replacing PDF content is non-trivial. I would neither count on such a functionality being available for free nor would I assume it to have a 100% hit rate. Could you instead change the PDF preparation process to put form fields in positions where you are to add content?

Comment: You can do it with python. Make sure that you replace the string with a string of the same length. Otherwise it will almost certainly corrupt the pdf.